Trying to hide rows in excel based on two values
i am trying to hid rows in excel between a row with value "P1" in column B and a row with value "P2" also in column B. i have tried, to my own shame i used Chatgpt for a part but i am stuck now. a part of the code succeeded in hiding the rows, but i was not able to let them reapear when i pushed the button. some of the things i tried are commented out,
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim startRow As Long
    Dim endRow As Long
    Dim cell As Range
    Dim Rng As Range
    
    ' Set the worksheet
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Calculatie")
    
    ' Find the start and end rows based on values in column B
    For Each cell In ws.Range("B:B")
        If cell.Value = "P1" And startRow = 0 Then
            startRow = cell.Row
        ElseIf cell.Value = "P2" And startRow <> 0 Then
            endRow = cell.Row
            Exit For
        End If
    Next cell
    
    'Set Rng = Selection
    
    'Set Rng = ws.Rows(startRow + 1 & ":" & endRow - 1)
    'Set Rng = ws.Range("startRow", "endRow")
    
    
    ' Hide rows between startRow and endRow
    If startRow > 0 And endRow > 0 Then
    'If Rng.Hidden = True Then
        'Selection.EntireRow.Hidden = True
        ws.Rows(startRow + 1 & ":" & endRow - 1).EntireRow.Hidden = True
    Else
        'Selection.EntireRow.Hidden = False
        'ws.Rows(startRow + 1 & ":" & endRow - 1).EntireRow.Hidden = False
        MsgBox "Start or end value not found in column B"
    End If
End Sub

what do i need to change to get this working?
i tried to make a range and change the hidden value, gave errors... so i put i back to the original code that worked...

If I understand you correctly, you want to toggle the visibility of the rows: First click on the button will hide them, next click will show them again.
To unhide hidden rows, just set the property Hidden to False.
So what you need is to check if the rows are already hidden. The following snippet will do that: It saves the Hidden-property of the first row below "P1" into a variable (isAlreadyHidden) and set the Hidden-Property of the rows to the opposite (Not isAlreadyHidden)
 If startRow > 0 And endRow > 0 Then
    Dim isAlreadyHidden As Boolean
    isAlreadyHidden = ws.Rows(startRow + 1).Hidden
    ws.Rows(startRow + 1 & ":" & endRow - 1).EntireRow.Hidden = Not isAlreadyHidden
Else
    MsgBox "Start or end value not found in column B"
End If


A workaround to check the next line Hidden state after P1 and set the sheet rows state to False something like this:
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim startRow As Long
Dim endRow As Long
Dim cell As Range
Dim Rng As Range

' Set the worksheet
Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Calculatie")

 'Insertion start
Dim g as Long 
On Error Resume Next
g = ws.Columns("B").Find("P1").Row
On Error GoTo 0
If Not IsEmpty(g) And rows(g + 1).Hidden = True Then
  ws.rows.Hidden = False
  Exit Sub
End If

 'insertion End

' Find the start and end rows based on values in column B
For Each cell In ws.Range("B:B")
    If cell.value = "P1" And startRow = 0 Then
        startRow = cell.Row
    ElseIf cell.value = "P2" And startRow <> 0 Then
        endRow = cell.Row
        Exit For
    End If
Next cell

'Set Rng = Selection

'Set Rng = ws.Rows(startRow + 1 & ":" & endRow - 1)
'Set Rng = ws.Range("startRow", "endRow")


' Hide rows between startRow and endRow
If startRow > 0 And endRow > 0 Then
'If Rng.Hidden = True Then
    'Selection.EntireRow.Hidden = True
    ws.rows(startRow + 1 & ":" & endRow - 1).EntireRow.Hidden = True
Else
    'Selection.EntireRow.Hidden = False
    'ws.Rows(startRow + 1 & ":" & endRow - 1).EntireRow.Hidden = False
    MsgBox "Start or end value not found in column B"
End If
End Sub

